# jasmine toEqual method not working with Header objects

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

`toEqual` is not working as expected when I try to test a `Header` object.

I isolated the problem in the following example:

```
 const foo = new Headers();
 const bar =  new Headers();
 bar.append('some', 'value'); // bar is mutated
 expect(foo).toEqual(bar); // returns true...
```

How can the spec pass although `foo` and `bar` are different ?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to grab the specific header value by its key. Jasmine may not be performing as deep a check as is needed to see the discrepancy. This will work better and only requires you to create one header object.

```
 const foo = new Headers();
 let newHeaderKey = 'some';
 let newHeaderValue = 'value';
 foo.append(newHeaderKey , newHeaderValue ); // foo is mutated
 expect(bar.headers.get(newHeaderKey )).toEqual(newHeaderValue ); // returns true...
```

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question, jasmine's `toEqual` method checks for strict equality.  In JavaScript (and TypeScript) two objects can only be considered 100% equal if they are the exact same object (the same instance of that object).  This means that you can only verify that the following will pass:

```js
expect(foo).toEqual(foo);
```

This sounds unhelpful, but it is useful in a large application when you NEED to know that you have the exact instance of the object that you want.

In regard to how to test this with jasmine, you can test the individual headers within the `Headers` object (e.g. you can verify that `foo.get('content-type')` is correct);

```js
expect(foo.get('content-type')).toEqual(bar.get('content-type'));
```